# Passing a list as a Parameter in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am a beginner to functional programming and I want to be able to read values from a console into a list, pass that list as a parameter, and then return the sum of the list in Scheme.

I want to get this result: (display (sum-list-members '(1 2 3 4 5))) but the user must enter these values at the console.

This is what I am working on:

```lisp
(begin

    (define count 0)


    (define sum-list-members
      (lambda (lst)
        (if (null? lst)
        0
        (+ (car lst) (sum-list-members (cdr lst))))))


    (display "Enter a integer [press -1 to quit]: ")
    (newline)

    (let loop ((i 0))               

        (define n(read))
        (sum-list-members (list n))

            (set! count i)      
            (if (not(= n -1))               

        (loop (+ i 1)))

    )

    (newline)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using chicken-scheme, I'd do it like this:

```
(define (read-number-list)
  (map string->number (string-tokenize (read-line))))
```

Define your `sum-list-members` as such:

```
(define (sum-list-members lst)
   (fold + 0 lst))
```

To get `string-tokenize` to work, you might have to use a certain `srfi`. Fold is pretty much the same thing as you wrote, except that it's a function that takes a function and initial value as parameters.

The function has to receive 2 parameters, the first parameter is the current value and the second parameter is the value returned by the previous call or the initial value.

Answer (score -1):

```
(do ((mlist () (cons n mlist))(n (read)(read)))
    ((= n -1) (display (apply + mlist))))
```

Comment: why reason downvote? although I think `sum-list-members` is to `cons` in a loop to create a list is expected to list on the argument that's obvious.